# Find peaks in a series?

Tags: php

I have got a series like this:

14, 13, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 19, 22, 24, 22, 18, 15, 14, 17, ...

If I plot these points on a chart on X-Y axis using these values as Y coordinates, then you'll see that there are peaks at 20 & 24.

I want to find all these peaks in the series

I tried:

```
$a=array(14, 13, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 19, 22, 24, 22, 18, 15, 14, 17  );
rsort($a);

echo $a[0];
echo $a[1];
```

But that doesn't give me the two peaks I see on the graph. The result of the code above is 24, and 22. But the peak on the graph were made by 20 and 24...

Is there a way I can detect the array to determine the peaks in the entire series?
I don't need a working code. Just some ideas I can work upon.

Comment: To find the peaks, you need to find the values where the surrounding values on both sides of the series are lower, not simply the highest values in the series

Comment: your argument looks flawed. how are you actually defining peaks? is 0 0 20 0 0 a peak? is 19 19 20 19 19 a peak?

Comment: `$peaks = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($a[$k-1]) && isset($a[$k+1]) && $a[$k-1] < $v && $a[$k+1] < $v) {
        $peaks[] = $v;
    }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) suggested, you need to check that each value in the array is greater than the previous and the next value. That's what defines a peak.

Just be sure to start from the 2nd index and finish on the nth-1 item or else you'll get an `Undefined offset` error.

```
$a = array(14, 13, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 19, 22, 24, 22, 18, 15, 14, 17);
$arr = [];

for($i=1; $i<count($a)-1; $i++){
    if($a[$i] > $a[$i+1] && $a[$i] > $a[$i-1]) {
        array_push($arr, $a[$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($arr); //returns: array(2) { [0]=> int(20) [1]=> int(24) }
```

---

Depending on your application, you might want to add some logic in case the case that 2 or more items "together" are a peak. For example, `22, 24, 24, 22, 18`. If this is something you want, just change the logic to check for `>=` on the next item:

```
if($a[$i] > $a[$i+1] && $a[$i] >= $a[$i-1]) {
```

This will yield the same result as above.

Comment: wayyy more elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$a=array(14, 13, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 19, 22, 24, 22, 18, 15, 14, 17  );

$last=0;
$peaks=array();
$upwards=false;
foreach( $a as $value )
{
    if( $value > $last )
    {
        $upwards = true;
    }
    if( $value < $last )
    {
        if( $upwards )
        {
            $peaks[] = $last;
        }
        $upwards = false;
    }
    $last = $value;
}

var_dump($peaks);
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to accept both the answers, but can't. Really appreciate the help :) You guys are all genius!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, guess it popped up because someone was editing, but here's my two cents' worth. This is better done without a loop:

```
<?php
$a = [14, 13, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 19, 22, 24, 22, 18, 15, 14, 17];
$b = array_filter(
    $a,
    function($v, $k) use($a) {return $k > 0 && $v > $a[$k-1] && $k + 1 < count($a) && $v > $a[$k+1];},
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
print_r($b);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [6] => 20
    [11] => 24
)
```